# filtering 1990 to 2020 in a csv but cant seem to get rid of 1965 and other years after until 1990 in panda

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

i cant seem to filter this data that goes from 1965 to 2020 so that i can have 1990 to 2020.

i have tried and multiple variations of it. in general im stuck and im not sure what to do from here. im a beginner in data analytics;-;

```
df['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year'])
```

```
Entity  Code    Year    Fossil Fuels (TWh)
0   Algeria DZA 1965    23.650
1   Algeria DZA 1966    28.783
2   Algeria DZA 1967    27.035
3   Algeria DZA 1968    28.680
4   Algeria DZA 1969    32.472
... ... ... ... ...
4158    Vietnam VNM 2016    691.114
4159    Vietnam VNM 2017    695.766
4160    Vietnam VNM 2018    824.193
4161    Vietnam VNM 2019    979.427
4162    Vietnam VNM 2020    942.366
```

Comment: Have you done the obvious `dfnew = df[df['Year'] >= 1990]`?

Comment: I SWEAR IT DIDNT WORK BEFORE I SWEAR. thank you lots though i thought it was a lot more complicated then that.

Answer (score 0):

type

```py
df = df[df.Year >= 1990]
```